# ActiveMQ consumer level timeout

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, producer-consumer

I trying to create a consumer level timeout in Active MQ (version 5.15.0). Consider one message is picked by a consumer but not able to acknowledge so in that case i want consumer to timeout so that same message can be picked by other consumer listening to broker.

My Producer code where I am setting two consumer listener:

```
public class JmsMessageListenerAckExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, Exception {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
      // Producer
      ConnectionFactory factory = createActiveMQConnectionFactory();
      connection = factory.createConnection();
      Session session = connection.createSession(false,
          Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      Queue queue = session.createQueue("customerQueue");
      String payload = "Important Task";
      Message msg = session.createTextMessage(payload);
      MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

      System.out.println("Sending text '" + payload + "'");
      producer.send(msg);

      // Consumer
      MessageConsumer consumer1 = session.createConsumer(queue);
      consumer1.setMessageListener(
          new AckMessageListener(false, "consumer1"));
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      System.out.println("Creating new message listener to acknowledge");
      producer.send(msg);
      MessageConsumer consumer2 = session.createConsumer(queue);
      consumer2.setMessageListener(
          new AckMessageListener(true, "consumer2"));
      connection.start();

      Thread.sleep(3000);
      session.close();
    } finally {
      if (connection != null) {
        connection.close();
      }
    }
  }

  private static ActiveMQConnectionFactory createActiveMQConnectionFactory() {
    // Create a connection factory.
    final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
        new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

    // Pass the username and password.
    connectionFactory.setUserName("user");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("user");
    return connectionFactory;
  }
}
```

This is my consumer listener:

```
public class AckMessageListener implements MessageListener {
  private boolean acknowledge;
  private String consumerName;

  public AckMessageListener(boolean acknowledge, String consumerName) {
    this.acknowledge = acknowledge;
    this.consumerName = consumerName;
  }

  public void onMessage(Message message) {
    boolean terminate = !acknowledge;
    try {

      System.out.println("ConsumerName="+consumerName+", Acknowledge="+acknowledge);
      if (acknowledge) {
        try {
          message.acknowledge();
        } catch (JMSException e1) {
          e1.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      System.out.println(message);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (terminate) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to simulate in a way that `consumer1` listen to message but does not acknowledge so that it timeout i am trying to release the thread, I am expecting my `consumer2` to pick it up and give acknowledgement to the message so that message get moved from "Messages Enqueued" state to "Messages Dequeued" state in broker but my `consumer2` is not able to receive any message events.

Is there something i am doing wrong. How do I achieve consumer level timeout with Active MQ?

Comment: This should be a good read for you https://www.pmichaels.net/2016/10/13/acknowledging-a-message-in-active-mq/

Answer (score 1):

One way of handling this would be to use transactions (http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-transactions-work.html). You call commit() on success, rollback() on failure or if session is closed before calling the commit() then re delivery will occur (http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html).

Comment: Even with transacted session and doing rollback still same consumer is picking the message. Is there any other configuration that I need to set?

Comment: Ok I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to preserve the message in case if your consumer 1 dies while processing a message, and then you want consumer 2 to pick that up. But it seems you want to rollback from one consumer and want second consumer to pick up the message. I don't know if there is an ActiveMQ (neat) way of doing this. ActiveMQ is reattempting delivery (in round robin fashion). I am not sure what is your end goal but would sending a copy of same message to both consumers work for you? If yes, you can use composite destinations for that.